# Nuxt 3 error, when i follow to the another link

Tags: nuxt.js, vuejs3

I have a list of cards(products for example), and when i follow to he card from the list i have error at this line:

about item null Card.vue:6 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'slug') at Proxy._sfc_render (Card.vue:6:37)
so, this means that vue clean my list variable when i follow the link and i am getting an error, how can i fix this?
here is my code:

```
    <script setup>
        const {  list } = defineProps(['list'])
    </script>
    
    <template>
        <div class="cards">
            <Card v-for="item in list" :item="item" />
        </div>
    </template>
```

```
<script setup>
    const {  item } = defineProps(['item'])
    </script>
    
    <template>
        <NuxtLink :to="'/page/' + item.slug" class="cards__item">
            123
        </NuxtLink>
    </template>
```

doing all according to nuxt 3 docs.

Comment: One of the array members in `list` is `null`. And you can't access a property of `null`.